Остановка аудио в сервисе при поступлении звонка или изменении аудиофокуса
Есть сервис, который запускает аудио. Если в уведомлении нажать "Стоп" также останавливает аудио.
Как сделать чтобы при поступлении звонка или при изменении аудиофокуса сервис останавливал аудио (т.е. останавливал сам плеер.. для этого в классе AudioPlayer есть методы AudioPlayer.stopPlayer(); и AudioPlayer.startPlayer(stream, audioSource, this)), а при окончании звонка автоматически запускал.
Мне нужно решение или решения (в зависимости от версий API) начиная с Android API 24.
public class AudioPlayerService extends Service {
    public static Context context;
    boolean isPlay = false;
    String stream;
    String audio;
    String img;
    String audioSource;

    public static final String KEY_STREAM = AudioPlayerService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_STREAM";
    public static final String KEY_AUDIO = AudioPlayerService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_RADIO";
    public static final String KEY_IMG = AudioPlayerService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_IMG";
    public static final String KEY_AUDIO_SOURCE = AudioPlayerService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_AUDIO_SOURCE"; //Источник аудио (интернет или локальные)

    private TelephonyManager tm;
    CallStateListener callStateListener;

    private void showNotification() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(AppConstants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, AudioPlayerService.class);
        closeIntent.setAction(AppConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pCloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, closeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        int notifyId = AppConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID.PLAYER_SERVICE_ID; // id уведомления

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String channelId = "cradioID";
            CharSequence channelName = "Radio Channel";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;

            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});

            if (notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.playing) + " " + audio)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setChannelId(channelId)
                    .setColor(Color.RED)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.icon_stop, getResources().getString(R.string.stop), pCloseIntent)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

            // Запуск службы в зависимости от версии Android
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                startForeground(notifyId, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK);
            } else {
                startForeground(notifyId, notification);
            }
        } else {
            String legacyChannelId = "legacy_channel_id";  // псевдоканал для старых версий Android
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, legacyChannelId)
                    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.playing) + " " + audio)
                    .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.open_list))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.icon_stop, getResources().getString(R.string.stop), pCloseIntent)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
            startForeground(notifyId, notification);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
            tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }

    private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    //Когда телефон звонит, то делаем паузу
                    if (isPlay) {
                        AudioPlayer.stopPlayer();
                        isPlay = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    //Когда телефон не звонит, то продолжаем проигрывание
                    if (!isPlay) {
                        isPlay = true;
                        AudioPlayer.startPlayer(stream, audioSource, AudioPlayerService.this);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        context = this;
        this.stream = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_STREAM);
        this.audio = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_AUDIO);
        this.audioSource = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_AUDIO_SOURCE);
        this.img = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_IMG);

        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(AppConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            isPlay = true;
            showNotification();
            AudioPlayer.startPlayer(stream, audioSource, this);

        } else if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(AppConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            isPlay = false;
            stopAudioService();
        }

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    private void stopAudioService() {
        Intent brIntent = new Intent(AppConstants.BROADCAST_ACTION);
        brIntent.putExtra(AppConstants.SERVICE_PARAM, AppConstants.SERVICE_STATUS);
        sendBroadcast(brIntent);

        AudioPlayer.stopPlayer();
        stopForeground(true);
        RadioPlayerActivity.isPlay = false;
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }

        AudioPlayer.stopPlayer();
        stopForeground(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}


А разве при поступлении звонка все автоматически не отключается?

Нет насколько я знаю.

Но у меня в телефоне когда кто-то звонит все отключается.

При поступлении звонка система в приоритетном порядке переключает аудиофокус на связь и все остальные аудио не слышны, с этим вопросов нет. Возможно я в задаче непонятно описал, мне нужно останавливать проигрыватель и запускать заново когда звонок завершится.

Есть широковещательные сообщения на которые нужно подписываться в системе через BroadcastReciver
